# htaccess protection - dialog doesn´t appear

Tags: .htaccess, authentication

I have a problem with my htaccess protection. First lets have a look at the sourcecode. This is the htaccess. Note: I don´t have a htaccess in the parent folder, so there is no protection from a parent element.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /fullPath/protection/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /fullPath/protection/.htgroup
require user devju

<Limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Ok, so this is the htpasswd in the protection directory:

```
devju:anfxCAFkVCb9E
```

and this is the htgroup (but it is irrelevant to the example):

```
superadmin: devju
```

Ok the problem is that sometimes, and currently permanent, the auth-dialog doesn´t appear and the client will redirected to the ErrorDocument 401. So why is that so? Do I have a wrong configuration or something else? I didn´t changed anything in the settings.

Note: Currently I don´t have enough points to comment, so I can´t answer to questions :(

Comment: use http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/ to protect the directory  and http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ to generate the password and follow the instruction given on these two links. hope it will help you

Comment: No, sorry that wasn´t helpful to me. The result would be like @BillyBigPotatoes said, but that is not the solution I´m searching for. This would allow all users which are listet in htpasswd to access the directory. I have to give only one defined user access. To the password-generator: I have builded one by myself, so I don´t need this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /fullPath/protection/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Comment: That would not be a very good solution. I have to define only one user who can access the site. So the solution you gave me would allow all users which are listet in htpasswd to access the directory!